# How to enable CORS in Nifi running in Docker?

Tags: docker, web-applications, cors, apache-nifi

I'm having a problem accessing the nifi API from a web app I'm building. This is the error I get:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ...

I know I need to enable CORS on the jetty server nifi runs on, and I've changed the web.xml in an attempt to do this. But every time I rebuild the image and stand up a container, all of my changes are overwritten. Is there an easier way to accomplish enabling CORS so that I can access the nifi api with my webapp? Or is there any insight on how to make my changes persist in the web.xml files on the docker container startup?